# MVC3 Show description from DataAnnotations attribute on .blur

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

mvc3 DataAnnotations has a Description attribute:

e.g.

```
[Display (Name="Title", Description="description about the title")]
public string Title { set; get};
```

in my view, I want to use jquery on .blur show the Description text that was entered.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     $("#title").blur(function () {
        ???
    });
});
```

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
//description here, not sure how to map it.
@Html.LabelFor()//description would go here
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
```

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think adding Description will add a title tag to your input element. You may probably want to mention that when you create the text box like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new {@title="Your description"})
```

that will generate a title tag for your input element and as minus4 mentioned, you can use jQuery to access that.

```
$(function () {
  $("#Title").blur(function () {
       alert($(this).attr("title"));
  });        
});
```

You probably want to use a generic selector instead of specific selector (ID), something like a class name of all those input elements

**EDIT :**  based on the comment about generic selector and specific selector

ID should be unique for each element, So If you have 8 elements, there will (and should) be 8 unique ids for the elements. in that case, you need to bind your function to 8 different items by ID like this

```
   $("#Title,#Name,#City,#JobTitle,#SomeOther,#LastName,#Hi,#Ho").blur(function () {
           alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });
```

But if you have a common class which is being applied to all these elements , you may use it like that (The below will bind the function to all elements which has the css class value `mySimpleClass`

```
   $(".mySimpleClass").blur(function () {
           alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });
```

You may use the other selectors like Child selectors. (The below code will bind your functionality to all input element of type text which is present in the `divContainer` div

```
   $("#divcontainer input type[text]").blur(function () {
           alert($(this).attr("title"));
    });
```

To Add the Css class to your input element while using Html.TextBox for HTML helper, you may use it like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new {@title="Your description", @class="mySimpleClass"})
```

Comment: thx, what do you mean "use a generic selector instead of specific selector (ID)"? I have 8 textboxes, should I just add @title to each textboxfor?

Answer (score 1):

i have never used description before, but assuming it adds maybe a title tag then you can use this:

```
var desc = $(this).attr("title");
alert(desc);
```